How do I automate creating new features from a shapefile based on specific field?
I have a shapefile of a country with district boundaries (Refer to the image below).

I want to create new features or shapefiles of individual district boundaries How do I automate the creation of these district boundaries from the shapefile? I'm using QGIS but a solution in Python or ArcGIS is also ok

Split vector layer in QGIS processing toolbox should do what you're after

@BenW yes this is the one I'm looking for. Thank you for the information.

There is a tool called split by attributes in arcgis. This will create multiple feature classes
